# Unable to install pgagent with application stack builder

Tags: postgresql, installation, pgadmin, pgagent

I'm trying to install pgagent in a windows environment. Postgresql version 9.6 is installed and application stack builder was installed with it. I have followed the steps, detailed [here](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.14/pgagent_install.html#service-installation-on-windows).

The first step in this guide is to create the extension in the maintenance db, and I am not able to do that.

**"ERROR:  could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/share/extension/pgagent.control": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01"**

Tryied to skip this step and go straight to the installation with application stack builder, but the pgAgent tool does not show up.

[image]

I also tried to install it as a service using the command line instead of stack builder.

`pgAent.exe INSTALL pgAgent -u postgres -p secret hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname=postgres user=postgres`

This worked to some degree. The only error I get is this.

**"Windows could not start pgAgent service on the local computer. Error 1069: The service did not start due to a logon failure."**

But I have tried all possible combinations of usernames, passwords, secrets, ports and so on....

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  I was able to get pgagent working by downloading and executing the stand-alone installation file pgagent-3.4.0-4-windows.exe from here: http://sbp.enterprisedb.com/getfile.jsp?fileid=11842

Answer (score 1):

I wound up installing the [Stack Builder Plus from EDB](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgresql). Unfortunately, you have to create an account, but it has a lot more options for which pgAgent version you want.  Note: You can use Stack Builder for only pulling a pgAgent installation executable and run that on your target servers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me :
first I accessed the postgres bin file using cmd: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin

then  i tapped this : 
pgAgent INSTALL pgAgent -u windowsUser-p windowspassword hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbaname=postgres user=postgres password=***

Answer (score 0):

Have you choosen a localy installed database before this step ?
You will need to have installed PostgresSql, CLI Commands and Stackbuilder to have the option of installing pgAgent via those eDB installers.